# How do I align elements vertically in Vuetify?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I have these social media buttons in the top left corner:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
<v-row v-for="(button, index) in socialMediaButtons" :key="index">
  <v-col>
    <v-btn fixed fab class="mt-5 ml-1"><v-icon>{{ button.logo }}</v-icon></v-btn>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

As you can see, the buttons are overlapping each other. How can I achieve that they have space between them vertically?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have `fixed` props, which makes `v-col` thinks there is nothing inside the column. So the height of the button is not calculated, which makes the buttons overlap.

Try something like this (example)

```
<v-row>
  <v-col sm="12">
    <v-btn fab dark small color="primary">
      <v-icon dark>mdi-minus</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-col>
  <v-col sm="12">
    <v-btn fab dark small color="pink">
      <v-icon dark>mdi-heart</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-col>
</v-row>;
```

**Your code**

```
<v-row v-for="(button, index) in socialMediaButtons" :key="index">
  <v-col sm="12>
    <v-btn fab class="mt-5 ml-1"><v-icon>{{ button.logo }}</v-icon></v-btn>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Comment: but I need my buttons to be fixed

Comment: In that case you need to have a div wrapper around `v-row` and use CSS - `position:fixed`. OR. you need to add as wrapper around each button with fixed height(which is same as that of button), then add `fixed` props to `v-btn`